# Exclude all from attributes where employee table does not have connection with in the pivot table

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
      Attributes   |           Pivot         |     Employees
                   |                         |
      attribute1   |  attribute1|employee1   |     employee1
      attribute2   |  attribute2|employee1   |
      attribute3   |                         |
```

I need to exclude all **attributes** that have no connection with **employee1** in **Pivot** table.
in this case **attribute3**.
What is the SQL query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from attributes a
where not exists (select 1
                  from pivot p
                  where p.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and
                        p.employee_id = @employee_id
                 );
```